# Anderson localization for fractional Laplacians

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, schrodinger-operators, fractional-calculus

There is a vast literature on Anderson localization, namely, the study of decay of eigenfunctions of operators on $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ such as
$$
-\Delta+\lambda V
$$
where $\Delta$ is the discrete lattice Laplacian and the potential $V$ is random say given by a vector $(V_{\mathbf{x}})_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^d}$ of iid standard normal variables. The constant $\lambda$ is the strength of disorder.

Did anyone study similar random operators
$$
(-\Delta)^{\alpha}+\lambda V
$$
with a fractional Laplacian?

I am in particular interested in references from the physics literature which provide some heuristics, e.g., a [scaling theory](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.42.673) à la Abrahams et al.

Comment: I remember Kamil Kaleta and Katarzyna Pietruska-Pałuba did some research on non-local operators with random potentials. Not sure if this is relevant to your question (and certainly not on the physics side), but anyway you may like to have a look at their [arXiv:1601.05597](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05597).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: thank you for this reference.

Answer (score 2):

Since fractional Laplacians describe diffusion on a fractal, for a physics application I would focus on Anderson localization on a fractal. The scaling theory mentioned in the OP has been applied to a fractal in [An attractive critical point from weak antilocalization on fractals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.02096).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Although, I am not sure about the validity of the equivalence between fractional Laplacian on the square lattice versus ordinary Laplacian on fractal lattices. I would prefer references on the former.